# Eval(AND expression) returns invalid syntax error

Tags: python

The function eval('4>1 AND 5>1') returns a syntax error with the marker at the end of the AND.  Why?

Comment: Because Python is case-sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your interpreter.

```
>>> 4>1
True
>>> 5>1
True
>>> 4>1 and 5>1
True
>>> eval('4>1 and 5>1')
True
```

However what you are doing is:

```
>>> 4>1 AND 5>1
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So when you do,

```
>>> eval('4>1 AND 5>1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    eval('4>1 AND 5>1')
  File "<string>", line 1
    4>1 AND 5>1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

You get the error. Change `AND` to `and` and it should be fine.